# Control-click on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, mouse-click

Control-clicking on my Mac stopped bringing up a menu. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do any of the other modifier keys bring up a menu? (Option+Click, Command+Click)

Comment: Do you not have a right mouse button or something?

Answer (score 1):

Try turning it off and on again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe control-click doesn't work for some apps. For example, I control click in chrome right now and nothing happens. But in Textmate it works.

Comment: control-click works in chrome, for me at least.